# HTML5 draw text that stays on the top

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a file called functions.js with diferent functions like:

1. bgImage()
2. drawImage()
3. setText()

My issue is that my text keeps staying behind.

What i want to do is, when i call setText() i can put text where i want.  And the text will be put on the top ofc the convas.  I know i need to call the image draw load functions first to get them to not overwrite my text.  But i did so in my JS.

So its very important that i can call the function setText() as many times as i want, after all images are drawn/set, and the text will be visible.

I want the text on the top.

Here is my code:

**functions.js**

```
var canvas = "";
var context = "";

function canvasInit() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function bgImage() {
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
        context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillStyle = pattern;
        context.fill();
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/wood-pattern.png';
}

function drawImage() {
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 50);
        context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
}

function    (text) {
    context.font = 'italic 40pt Calibri';
    context.fillText(text, 150, 100);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',ready);
        function ready() {
            canvasInit();
            bgImage();
            drawImage();
            setText("Yo");
            setText("heyyyy");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Updated test that do not work:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',ready);
        function ready() {
            canvasInit();
            bgImage(function() {
               setText(); 
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**functions.js**

```
var canvas = "";
var context = "";

function canvasInit() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function bgImage(callback) { // add parameter for function

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
        context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillStyle = pattern;
        context.fill();

        if (typeof callback === 'function')  {
            callback();  // invoke callback function
        }

    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/wood-pattern.png';

}

function drawImage() {
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 50);
        context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
}

function setText() {
    context.font = 'italic 40pt Calibri';
    context.fillText("Yoo adfa ds asd a sd", 150, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got my code to work.  However i found some framework called "http://kineticjs.com/" and i solved my issues using that.

Thanks for the comments Ken - Abdias Software.  I did also take a look at what you linked to in your profile description.  Looking really neat ;)

However i feel its the best to accept the answer that solved my problem, and i solved it myself.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your image loading is asynchronous: before the image has finished loading you draw your text as the function exits after setting the source. Then when the image has finished loaded the onload function is called and the image drawn on top of whatever is drawn previously (in this case the text).

You need to implement a callback handler for your functions for this to work - for example:

```
function bgImage(callback) { /// add parameter for function

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
        context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillStyle = pattern;
        context.fill();

        if (typeof callback === 'function')  
            callback();  /// invoke callback function
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/wood-pattern.png';
}
```

Then you use it:

```
bgImage(function() {
   setText(); 
});
```

You will of course need to do this with the other image loading functions as well. Tip: If you end up with a long chain it's probably better to assign non-anonymous functions instead of inline them as in the last example.

**Update**:

Just for clarity: it's important that the function provided is provided as a reference and not a result from calling, for example: use the callback this way:

```
bgImage(setText);   /// correct
```

not this way:

```
bgImage(setText()); /// wrong
```

With the parenthesis the `setText` is simply invoked and its result is passed as a callback. This means the text will be drawn first and then `bgImage` is called.

Comment: Ok that look very nice.. I have some questions.. Lets say that i want to call 10 images, and then 25 texts after that.  I can already see the mad function list in my head.  what would you do in this case?   This thing is that i need to be able to input text dynamicly, whenever i need to aswell.  So i cant rely on drawing everything on the load.  I need to be able to insert text lets say on a click event on a button.

Comment: I cant get your code example to work either.  I just copy pasted what you wrote and replaced.

Comment: If i just drawImage() it works, but in my code i dont use drawImage().

Comment: @Daniel I used your code; only added the callback to it (what errors do you get?). For many operations it is probably better to change it to use an array (of urls) instead of calling it individually for each image. Then when you have loaded all the images within that function (which takes an array) you do a callback to the function which takes an array of texts. The text can be object which also contains position and styles.

Comment: @Daniel Your error is this: `bgImage(setText());` must be: `bgImage(setText);` without parenthesis for  setText or else you are simply calling the function and return its result to bgImage. You must only reference it.

Comment: I updated the code again, i cant see the text.  Man im getting a bit confused now.  I made alert() calls when the different functions are called.  Take a look at it